# How can I convert String (which is actually Bitmap) to IFormFile in asp.net core 1.0 c#

Tags: java, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Basically what I am trying to do is sending a string which was bitmap(I converted into string ) and send t to Asp.net core 1.0 web application/api. I want to save that image into the hosted application files and path of that image to database but I do not understand how can I convert that string into IFormFile so I can copy It to the specific path.

```
        List<byte> splitBytes = new List<byte>();
        string byteString = "";

        foreach (var chr in obj.bitmapstr)
        {
            byteString += chr;

            if (byteString.Length == 3)
            {
                splitBytes.Add(Convert.ToByte(byteString));
                byteString = "";
            }
        }

        if (byteString != "")
            splitBytes.AddRange(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(byteString));

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(splitBytes.ToArray()))
        {

           

             // SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image img = SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.FromStream()

            //  ms.Write(splitBytes.ToArray(), 0, splitBytes.ToArray().Length);


            //   var img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

            //do something with image.
        }
```

I have tried converting it to Byte array but don't know what to do with that.

```
             Uri path=data.getData();
               
            Bitmap bitmap=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(),path);
            phtotimage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
             phtotimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String bitMapToString=BitMapToString(bitmap);
           getconnection("url",bitMapToString);
```

This is the code in android studio to get the file and convert it into string and pass that file

Comment: You should use Base64 to encode your image

Comment: the image is allready in Base64  I am unable to convert it to IFormFile or image . I have seen many codes where they used Image.FromStream but in my case  in Image.FromStream     FromStream does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Bitmap

A `bitmap` is a type of memory organization or image file format used to store digital images. The term bitmap comes from the computer programming terminology, meaning just `a map of bits`, a spatially mapped array of bits. Now, along with pixmap, it commonly refers to the similar concept of a spatially mapped array of pixels.

It's `"raw"` image files, which store raw bitmaps with no `header`, `size` or other information.

> IFormFile

Meanwhile, `IFormFile` has the following structure:

```
public interface IFormFile
{
    string ContentType { get; }
    string ContentDisposition { get; }
    IHeaderDictionary Headers { get; }
    long Length { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    string FileName { get; }
    Stream OpenReadStream();
    void CopyTo(Stream target);
    Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null);
}
```

From here, you can see the difference between `String`(`=Bitmap`) and `IFormFile`.
So that won't convert success as you expect.

**Convert base64 string to FormFile**

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\yourfile", Convert.FromBase64String(bitmapstr)))
        {
            var formFile = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null, Path.GetFileName(stream.Name))
            {
                Headers = new HeaderDictionary(),
                ContentType = "YOUR CONTENT TYPE HERE"
            };
        }
```

Comment: can u tell me how can we send this type of request in volley ...cuz I'm using volley ...... what that actually sends in part (2) ...a  String  or MultipartBody file or both......... and In part (1) what is meant by "yourfile"  ....a place where I want to store image?

Comment: @Ahmed Ishtiaq I don't think solution 2 is suitable for your situation. It's kinda complex and useless. Let's back to save bitmap from str/byte[] on server  local path.

Comment: public static void WriteAllBytes (string path, byte[] bytes); yes, "yourfile" is the [path] saves the files to the local file system.

Comment: Yeah as you say It would be easy If i directly save bitmapstr to the database ....so yeah that's easy....... Thank you @Michelle Wang  ..... I really appreciate that.

Comment: what will be in the content type?